# How does facebook app link work without declaring LSApplicationQueriesSchemes?

Tags: ios, ios9, url-scheme

In iOS 9 apps can't use `canOpenURL` to check if application installed or not.

> If your (iOS 9.0 or later) app calls this method using a scheme you
>   have not declared, the method returns false, whether or not an
>   appropriate app for the scheme is installed on the device.

but I am wondering how facebook app succeed to direct the user to appstore if the application is not installed , or to open target application if it's installed !

facebook can't list all apps in LSApplicationQueriesSchemes !

Thanks

Comment: may be its an exception apple made, because apple has option for Facebook settings specially in settings app. But where you need this for your application. I mean what you want to achieve actually?

Answer (score 1):

From `canOpenURL:` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplication/1622952-canopenurl):

> Unlike this method, the openURL: method is not constrained by the
>   UIDefaultLaunchStoryboard requirement: If an app that handles a scheme
>   is installed on the device, the openURL: method works, whether or
>   not you have declared the scheme.

So, they do the following:

1) Try to call `openURL:` with fb-compliant urls, for example `fb[app-id]://authorize...` until it returns true (I have checked it, they are calling a lot of urls, for example `fb[app-id]lite`, `fb[app-id]mac`, `fb[app-id]paid`, `fb[app-id]green`, etc). If it succedes, target app opens.

2) If there is no success with calling `openURL:`, they try to call `canOpenURL:` with `http://itunes.apple.com/app/...` url and then call `openURL:` with same url. User is redirected to App Store.